# Add an element around root element of given XML file that is stored in org.w3c.dom.Document

Tags: java, xml, xml-parsing, saxparser, domparser

So i am trying to do this. Add new root element and wrap old one in it.

Given this as starting condition

```
// this part uses SAXParser
org.w3c.com.Document = xmlSrc.parse(is); // *is* is InputStream
```

The initial condition is not really negotiable but I am open to hear comments there too

So given this xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root1>
   <elem>...</elem>
</root1>
```

I need in Java to generate an InputStream that will contain xml file in it of this format

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<newroot>
   <root1>
       <elem>...</elem>
   </root1>
</newroot>
```

Stored in some InputStream isNewXML

I am curious what is the best way to go about doing this.
I am new to Java and java has billion ways to do the same thing so out in dark which would be the best

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using your example input, this creates the requested output. Ideally, you would handle exceptions and close inputstreams, output streams, and writers properly:

```
import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.io.Writer;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class XmlTest
{

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        InputStream is = new FileInputStream("test.xml");
        DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder builder = factory.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document oldDoc = builder.parse(is);
        Node oldRoot = oldDoc.getDocumentElement();
        Document newDoc = builder.newDocument();
        Element newRoot = newDoc.createElement("newroot");
        newDoc.appendChild(newRoot);
        newRoot.appendChild(newDoc.importNode(oldRoot, true));

        ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        DOMSource domSource = new DOMSource(newDoc);
        Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(out);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(writer);
        TransformerFactory tf = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = tf.newTransformer();
        transformer.transform(domSource, result);
        writer.flush();

        InputStream isNewXML = new ByteArrayInputStream(out.toByteArray());

    }

}
```

Comment: i just found the same solution and just finished making it work for me but it is the exactly same principal as yours so marking it as answer.. thanks!

Comment: http://helpdesk.objects.com.au/java/how-to-insert-new-root-node-in-xml-dom-document
in case you wonder where i found almost same solution....

Comment: In reality, the easiest solution is probably to just read the InputStream using a BufferedReader and write to a new OutputStream (via a Writer). You would just write the new root tag after reading the first and last lines. You might be able to cut down a lot of memory usage that way.

Answer (score 6):

A `Document` is also a `Node` – the root element is the first and only child of the document, and you can manipulate the child nodes of the Document like any other:

```
Document doc = parser.parse(new File("build.xml"));

Element newRoot = doc.createElement("newroot");
newRoot.appendChild(doc.getFirstChild());
doc.appendChild(newRoot);

// output to wrapped.xml
Transformer transformer = TransformerFactory.newInstance().newTransformer();
transformer.transform(new DOMSource(doc), new StreamResult(new File("wrapped.xml")));
```

This would also be fairly easy to do with StAX if you ever need to process files where the overhead of DOM parsing would be significant.

Comment: this is missing some step because you output doc which is never changed... also the original xml can have more than one nested element

Comment: @grobartn Have you actually tried the code? I don't think you understand how it works.

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
import java.io.File;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

import org.w3c.dom.Attr;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;

public class WriteXMLFile {

    public static void main(String argv[]) {

      try {

        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();

        // root elements
        Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
        Element rootElement = doc.createElement("root");
        doc.appendChild(rootElement);



        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("build.xml"));

        // Output to console for testing
        // StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);

        transformer.transform(source, result);

        System.out.println("File saved!");

      } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
      } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
}
```