# how to append the xml string to existing xml file using xstream

Tags: java, xml, marshalling, xstream, unmarshalling

I am using xstream to marshal / unmarshal between java object to / from xml, one question is, is there a right solution to solve my problem (using xstream or other advanced method, instead of pure java API).
   The existing XML file can grow quite big (more than 200 mb, for example), and I like to append the new xml to this existing XML file, but without unmarshal the existing XML file first, simply append it to the end (before the root element).
   Please advice, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You could load the first XML as org.w3c.dom.Document and import the second one as org.w3c.dom.Element:

```
Element nodeToImport = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder().parse( secondXmlFile ).getDocumentElement();
dom.importNode( nodeToImport, true );
...
```

There is a similar example here, but with a new node around the root one: [Add an element around root element of given XML file that is stored in org.w3c.dom.Document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8318693/add-an-element-around-root-element-of-given-xml-file-that-is-stored-in-org-w3c-d)